# Modal to interrupt form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog

I have a form that I'm using to execute an account cancellation. I'm trying to display a pure CSS modal form to interrupt the form post so that the user can confirm the submission. So far, to achieve this, I have triggered the modal on form submission. Using the code below however the modal appears but does not interrupt the post, i.e. the post occurs.

Does anyone know how to get the modal to interrupt the submission until a further button within the modal is pressed to confirm the post?

Form:

```
    <form method='post' action='' onsubmit='return validate();'>
      <fieldset>
        <input type='hidden' id='cancel' name='cancel' value='cancel'>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Modal Javascript Trigger:

```
<script>
function validate() {
    var result = document.getElementById('myLink').click();
//    var result = confirm("Do you want to submit!");
    return result;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

to a type `button`

```
<input type='button' id='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

Handle button `click` so it opens `confirm` or whatever confirmation thing you will be using.
And then, based on the result `yes` or `no` submit the form http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

The problem with your implementation it that

```
document.getElementById('myLink').click();
```

doesn't really return `true` or `false`, at least the result cannot be interpreted as what you expect